# Add additional Storefront URL with CLI

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I install Shopware 6 on CLI. My shop is reachable over HTTP and HTTPS.

The cli-installer will create a storefront with my given URL like `https://demo.shop`.

My problem now is that I need the shop to be reachable without TLS too. How can I add another Storefront URL?

I tried to use the command `bin/console sales-channel:create:storefront --id=e28bf43c262f4343938a7b8a841ed136 --url=http://demo.shop` but this will fail with

`6:06:05 CRITICAL  [console] Error thrown while running command "sales-channel:create:storefront --id=e28bf43c262f4343938a7b8a841ed136 --url='http://demo.shop'". Message: "Expected command for "sales_channel" to be "Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Write\Command\InsertCommand". (Got: Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Write\Command\UpdateCommand)" ["exception" => Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Write\Command\WriteTypeIntendException^ { …},"command" => "sales-channel:create:storefront --id=e28bf43c262f4343938a7b8a841ed136 --url='http://demo.shop'","message" => "Expected command for "sales_channel" to be "Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Write\Command\InsertCommand". (Got: Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Write\Command\UpdateCommand)"]`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name of the command suggests it is only meant to create new sales channels, not for updating an existing one.

Why not create the additional domain using the [administration web-interface](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/saleschannel#domain)?

If you can't access the web-interface for some reason you could change the domain with the command `bin/console sales-channel:update:domain` instead. This will change the domain for *all* sales channels unless you provide a specific one to replace. See the help option of the command regarding that.

To actually create additional sales channel domains you may also use the API endpoint, see [here](https://swagger.docs.fos.gg/#/Sales%20Channel%20Domain/createSalesChannelDomain) or [here](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/c2NoOjE0MzUxMzI3-sales-channel-domain).

Comment: What I do is a automated setup, therefore I cannot use the admin. I will look into the API if that might be a solution.
`sales-channel:update:domain` does not help because it only changes domains that already exist. My problem is, that the CLI setup only creates one URL unlike the web-installer which creates both http and https URLs.

Comment: I checked the API way and I will not be able to go this route. I would need to build a custom API client that fetches all the required IDs from Shopware before I could send a API Call that creates a new Storefront URL. There are too many dependencies to languages, snippet-sets and more. I do not know how to make this work inside my simple bash deployment script.

Comment: Presumably you just want to copy an existing domain and just change the value of the url? The API has a clone endpoint: `POST /api/_action/clone/sales-channel-domain/{existingSalesChannelDomainId}`. In the the request payload you can overwrite fields of the clone: 
`{"overwrites": { "url" : "http://new.url.tld" }, "cloneChildren": false }`
You'd just have to fetch the id of the domain to be cloned from your sales channel first.